# How to Generate Haar Feature?

Tags: opencv, haar-wavelet

I don't understand how to generate haar like features in images using java. I am getting task to make a system of head detection using haar like features and evolving classification function as classifiers. 
Please help me.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please consider being more specific next time or simply edit your question to express the problems you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

- you don't *generate* cascades from java, there's c++ apps for that. (opencv_traincascade)
- to *use* them later, look at [CascadeClassifier](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html)

Comment: Thanks
In my homework, I want to make head detection using haar features for feature extraction and evolving classification function (ECF). Can I use opencv for my work?